# i need to question my database about a word received from another aplication, my tables are related on a many to many relashionship

Tags: python, sql, mysql

i have 2 tables one market, another brand , so when a client search for a brand i need to return all the markets where he can find that brand.

Comment: Er...could you elaborate a little on your table definitions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your dd looks like this:

market(id, name)

brand(id, name)

market_brand(fk_market_id, fk_brand_id)

your query would look something like this:

```
select m.name
  from brand b
  join market_brand mb on mb.fk_brand_id = b.id
  join market m on m.id = mb.fk_market_id
 where b.name = 'your_brand'
```

Comment: @user392502: Absolutely. Can't help you with that though, don't know any python. You should ask another question to get that answered :)